# How to convert spring 3.1 classNameString in properties file to class?

Tags: spring-mvc, properties

I can easily configure in XML but not in @Configuration.

Properties

```
spring.view.class=org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView
spring.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Code

```
@Bean
public UrlBasedViewResolver viewResolver() throws ClassNotFoundException {
  //ViewResolver Setting
  Class viewResolverClass = env.getPropertyAsClass("spring.view.class", Class.class);
  String viewResolverPrefix = env.getProperty("spring.view.prefix");
  String viewResolverSuffix = env.getProperty("spring.view.suffix");
  UrlBasedViewResolver viewResolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
  viewResolver.setViewClass(viewResolverClass);
  viewResolver.setPrefix(viewResolverPrefix);
  viewResolver.setSuffix(viewResolverSuffix);
  return viewResolver;
}
```

Error

```
throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView] from source type [String] to target type [Class]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Error messages too obvious and says all:

> Cannot convert value ... from source type [String] to target type [Class]

So, you should manually convert `String` to `Class` like this:

```
viewResolver.setViewClass(Class.forName(viewResolverClass));
```